# Measurable function on specific sigma algebra in cartesian of $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $ X = \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ and $ \mathcal{F} = \left\{ B \times \mathbb{R} : B \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}) \right\}$ be a sigma field on $ X $, where $\mathcal{B}$ is the smallest sigma field containing all Borel sets. Prove that if a $ f:X \to \mathbb{R} $ is measurable on $\mathcal{F}$, then for arbitrary $x, y_{1}, y_{2}$ we have $f(x, y_1) = f(x, y_2)$.

From my understanding, we have to prove, that the $f$ function only dependent on the first coordinate $x$. I've been trying to prove it by contraposition, but it doesn't seem to lead anywhere.

Does the $\impliedby$ hold as well?

Answer (score 1):

Let $(x,y)\in X$. $A=\{f(x,y) \}$ is a measurable subset of $\mathbb{R}$ so $f^{-1}(A)$ is a measurable subset of $X$. So there exists $B\in B(\mathbb{R})$ such that $f^{-1}(A)=B\times \mathbb{R}$. Clearly $x\in B$ so $\forall y'\in \mathbb{R}$ we have $(x,y')\in f^{-1}(A)$ so $f(x,y')=f(x,y)\forall y' \in \mathbb{R}$.
The converse is not true, take a non measurable function $g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and define $f(x,y)=g(x)\ \forall (x,y)\in X$. Then $f$ depends only on the first coordinate but $f$ is not measurable.